# how to sort the string according to the integer values

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Here i have tried

```
let sen = ("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a")

let sen2 = sen.split(" ")

//console.log(sen2)

sen2.sort()

console.log(sen2)
```

the output should be like this

```
rearrange("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a") ➞ "This is a Test"

rearrange("4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2") ➞ "For the good of the people"

rearrange(" ") ➞ ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
function rearrange(sen){
let sen2 = sen.split(" ");
sen2.sort(function(a, b){
   return parseInt(a.replace(/\D/g,'')) - parseInt(b.replace(/\D/g,''));
});
sen2 = sen2.map(a => a.replace(/\d/g,''));
return sen2.join(" ");
}
```

> You may also need some error handling (In case some words dont have numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You can split based on the numeric value by selecting the number present in word by regex and sort on this numeric value.

```js
const rearrange = (sentence) => {
  if(sentence.trim() === "") return "";
  return sentence
    .trim()
    .split(" ")
    .map(word => [word.match(/\d+/)[0], word])
    .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
    .map(([, word]) => word.replace(/\d+/, ''))
    .join(" ");
}

console.log(rearrange("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a")) //"This is a Test"
console.log(rearrange("4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2"))  //"For the good of the people"
console.log(rearrange(" ")) // ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNumber(s) {
    var r = /\d+/;
    return s.match(r) || 0;
}

function reArrange(s) {
    let s2 = s.split(" ")
    s2.sort(function(a, b){return getNumber(a) - getNumber(b)});
    return s2.join(' ')
}

console.log(reArrange("4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sentence1 = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a t10at";
let sentence2 = "4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2";
let sentence3 = " ";

function Order(s){
  let ordered=[];
  let nums = s.match(/\d+/g); // get numbers from sentence
  if(nums){ // if numbers exist
    let numArr=nums.map(Number); // convert string to number
    let sortedNum= [...numArr].sort((a,b)=> a-b); // sort numbers
    let words= s.replace(/\d+/g,'').split(' ') // get words without numbers
    sortedNum.map(i=> ordered.push(words[numArr.indexOf(i)])) // get words with order
  }
  return ordered.join(' ');
}

console.log(Order(sentence1));
console.log(Order(sentence2));
console.log(Order(sentence3));
```